# JSX is parsing before returning the data from a function in react Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-class-based-component

I am calling a function from the render method to fetch the updated data like this. but i am not getting the data on page because before getting the data my jsx is parsing .
Here is my code

```
private fetchMessages = async () => {
const isArray = Array.isArray(this.props.messages);
let messagesData: any;

console.log(this.props.messages);
messagesData = this.props.messages;
if (!isArray) {
  const result = await this.props.messages.fetchByOffset({
    offset: null,
  });
  const results = result.results;
  messagesData = results.map((value: any) => {
    return value.data;
  });
}
return await messagesData;
```

};

in render function i am calling like this

```
 private getData() {
this.fetchMessages().then(messageResponse => {
  this.jetMessages = this.processCustomMessageArray(messageResponse);

  return new ArrayDataProvider<null, ojMessage.Message>(this.jetMessages);

});
return null;
```

}

```
render(props: Readonly<Props>): ComponentChild {
    this.jetMessagesDataprovider = this.getData();
    
    return (
      <div
        id={`${this.uid}_stickycontainer`}
        class="oj-sp-messages-banner-sticky-container"
      >
        <oj-messages
          id={`${this.uid}_messagecontainer`}
          messages={this.jetMessagesDataprovider}
          displayOptions={this.computedCategoryOption}
        >
          <template slot="messageTemplate" render={this.renderMessage} />
        </oj-messages>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you offer a MRE? I see your code doesn't trigger the update function. Maybe this is the problem

Comment: @Prablion No error , Just the messages are not displaying on the page. because jetMessagesDataprovider is getting null as jsx is parsing before returning the data from getData() method

Comment: Did you call [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)?
and your second code piece is lacking a `}`